# Can't get main_ip with Ansible Vulrt

Tags: ansible, cloud, vultr

I create an instance and try to display the IP using the playbook, but it tells me that there is no such value. although if you look at the output of information for this instance, it is there. what to do?

```
  - name: Create an instance using OS
    vultr.cloud.instance:
      state: present
      api_key: "{{api}}"
      hostname: "{{ddns_password}}"
      label: test
      plan: vhp-1c-2gb-amd
      backups: true
      enable_ipv6: false
      region: ams
      os: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x64
      ssh_keys:
        - u01
        - u02
        - u03
      tags: 
        - "{{tag}}"
    register: my_droplet

  - name: Preparation and transfer of information
    vultr.cloud.instance_info:
      api_key: "{{api}}"
      label: test
    register: ipv4addr

  - name: Show IP
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: ipv4addr.main_ip
```

[image]

Please, look at my code and say where my mistake.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: On the question at hand, the `main_ip` is under the list named `vultr_instance_info`, so: `ipv4addr.vultr_instance_info.0.main_ip`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
Thank you! This helped me )